# Can wither skeletons spawn on any nether bricks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As in, I'm wondering if I was to take bricks from the fortress and bring them somewhere else with all the other conditions for their spawning. Would they still spawn in a non fortress area with nether bricks?

Answer (score 9):

Wither Skeletons spawn anywhere **within the bounding box of a fortress** regardless of the specific solid block.

Comment: Effectively, you can also expand the platform within the box so that there is more space for spawns!

Comment: @Potterton does this bounding box update tho?

Comment: The box stays the same. There is just unused space (normally most effective at intersections) that has no blocks. I don't know the size from the top of my head and will update this when I do.

Answer (score 3):

Wither skeletons can only spawn within the immediate area around Nether fortresses, so you can't take the bricks and place them somewhere away from the fortress, and still expect them to spawn on those bricks since they're too far away from the Nether fortress chunks.